# Is there scientific research on canine optimal nutrition

Tags: nutrition, dogs

We have recently adopted a puppy and been looking into healthy diet for optimal health for her.

I have been wondering for a while about any scientific evidence around dog diet and more specifically around the famous “raw vs cooked chicken bones for dogs” theory and decided to post my question here.

Is it true that cooked chicken bones are dangerous for dogs when raw chicken bones are safe?

Other than anecdotal information I was unable to find any publications on veterinary medicine journals studying the subject and I was impressed by the astonishing absence of veterinary papers in general.

It appears that in veterinary science there is more personal opinion and strong beliefs than clinical trials and research. This was a big surprise to me and even more surprising the face that people are happy to believe these theories without asking for proof.

While in human medical science theories are formed by researching and testing a hypothesis, in veterinary science it appears that there are many theories that are formed by anecdotal evidence.

Here is just one of many examples of how dietary theories are formed in human medicine.

https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2728487

Are you aware it any similar publications in veterinary medicine around dog diet and health effects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong forum for this question.

Comment: I'll note that many questions regarding human health get very little scientific research.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: To get a valid research on the "bones question", one would need to have groups of animals fed with each type, or at least to have a reliable statistics of feeding with respect to the (possibly existing) statistics of injuries. I doubt such statistics exists, and that such an experiment would be justified: _clearly_, raw bones are safer simply because they are softer and because dogs evolved to eat them, but safety is a relative concept, and the added danger of cooked bones may be insignificant. [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) is perhaps a better forum to discuss this.